# Laravel validating something else after form-request validation

Tags: laravel, validation, request

How can I validate something else after the regular validation in a form-request?
I need to verify that a folder does exists or not based on the name given in a input.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateFolder extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->can('create folders'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|between:1,64|string'
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to use the same `name` when I validate that the folder exists or not after the regular validation. The docs didn't specify anything useful as I could see.

Comment: Can you specify the location where you want to check if folder exists or not ?

Comment: Sure, I want to check if the folder exists or not in: `public/files/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom rule as a closure, so other rules will be same.

```
return [
    'name' => ['required','between:1,64','string',function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if (file_exists(public_path('files/').$value)) {
            $fail(':attribute directory already exists !');
        }
    }]
]
```

I hope you understand.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball Glad to know it works. you can see customization of rules over here, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a mechanism to write a custom rule for validation. Please have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Furthermore, I would suggest using a Storage object to check whether a file exists or not will be a more convenient and robust solution. One can refer to the official documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#retrieving-files

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CreateFolder extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->can('create folders'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 
                       'between:1,64', 
                       'string',
                       function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                         if (!Storage::disk('local')->exists('file.jpg')) {
                           $fail($attribute.' does not exist.');
                         }
                       }, 
                      ];
       ]
    }
}
```